# java , inserting between duplicate chars in String

Tags: java, string

Write Java program that insert '#' between any duplicate letters that are placed right next to each.
For example
Given the following string “Hello world” the output should be “Hel#lo world”

```
    String str = "Hello java world";

    char a = '#';

    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++ ) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i+1)){
                String temp = str + a;
                System.out.println(temp);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried writing some code yet?  Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You haven't actually asked a question, nor have you shown the code that you've written in attempting to solve this problem. [Please have a look at this introductory page.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for showing us your code. What does it do? If it isn't doing what you want it to do, is there something specific you don't understand about why it does what it does?

Comment: This code obviously throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` as well as it does not insert the `'#'` between consecutive identical letters. @Serii why don't you describe what the problem of your code is? The `Exception` is thrown because of the condition used in your `if` statemtent (`str.charAt(i+1)` tries to access an invalid index at the end of the loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could try:

**Example 1: Using REGEX**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "Hello worlld this is someething cool!";
        //add # between all double letters
        String processingOfText = text.replaceAll("(\\w)\\1", "$1#$1");
        System.out.println(processingOfText);

    }
```

**Example 2: Using string manipulations**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "Hello worlld this is someething cool!";
        for (int i = 1; i < text.length(); i++) 
        {
            if (text.charAt(i) == text.charAt(i - 1)) 
            {
                text = text.substring(0, i) + "#" + text.substring(i, text.length());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(text);

    }
```

And a lot more...

Comment: Thank you very much MS90 it is working very well!!!